# Which is faster / more efficient?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Which one of the following is faster / more efficient / less memory intensive?

This:

```
$("#my-div").responsiveSlides({
    auto: true,
    pager: true,
    pause:true,
    nav: false,
    timeout: 3000,
    speed: 500,
    maxwidth: 482,
    namespace: "transparent-btns"
});
```

Or this:

```
$target = $("#my-div");
if ($target.length !== 0) {

    $target.responsiveSlides({
        auto: true,
        pager: true,
        pause:true,
        nav: false,
        timeout: 3000,
        speed: 500,
        maxwidth: 482,
        namespace: "transparent-btns"
    });

}
```

Comment: `#my-div` does that div remain there all the time?

Comment: If a plugin is written correctly, it does nothing when jQuery element's length is 0, so this check is redundant.

Comment: @raina77ow what if it wasn't written correctly? What could be the impact?

Comment: Micro-optimisation. If there is a difference you'll have wasted far more time finding it than you will ever recover in increased performance. If you really want to know, profile it.

Comment: There is an infinity of ways a piece of code can be incorrect. Why assume it would be incorrect in one particular way? You can't assume the behaviour of bad code.

Comment: +1 to what @Amadan said: there's no limits on how bad the code can be. For example, a plugin could think that it always works with jQuery object consisting of exactly one element, hence using its underlying DOM directly, via `this[0].innerHTML` or things like this. That'll obviously break when jQuery element is empty. Even in this case, it'll be easier to fix the plugin then to make checks in the client's code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first snippet...

- looks for DOM element with specified ID, wrap the results in jQuery object
- calls the plugin on that object, passing it as plugin's context (`this`)
- if the plugin doesn't store reference to that jQuery object in some inner variable that is exposed to the outer world via functions, discards it (as it's no longer referenced by anything)

Now, if plugin is written correctly, it process its element via `this.each` or similar mechanism. That means an empty jQuery object will be processed instantly.

The second snippet does the same with two additional things:

- stores the jQuery object in a variable (so it'll be discarded only when the *variable* goes out of scope, no matter how plugin is written)
- checks the jQuery object length

The latter, as I said, is most probably a redundant check. And the former is useful when you're going to reuse this element later. Otherwise the first snippet should be considered an optimal solution, even though it will barely matter in an application of any meaningful scale.